# SVG + HTML into PDF in Ruby on Rails or JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdf, svg

I have a requirement to download html + svg content into PDF.

1. I have tried using javascript - could not succeed(it supports html -> pdf and svg -> pdf but not svg+html -> pdf)
2. I tried using ruby on rails by sending the svg content to the rails framework and converting to image(using image magick) and generate PDf(wkhtmltopdf) using the image and html code. Downloaded svg has lost clarity.

Can any one help me with this, guide me if there are direct tools or technique to achieve the functionality

Comment: PhantomJS is able to render HTML+SVG, then save to PDF. It is JavaScript, but requires a separate executable (not plain NodeJS).

Comment: Thanks amadan . I will experiment and get back to you..

Comment: Will it allow me to generate part of page including HTML + SVG(may be a div with html and svg) to PDF